# Is it possible to use TCPDF to load html files or blade views?

Tags: laravel, tcpdf

At first I used `barryvdh/laravel-snappy` because it had good support for RTL languages and a simple way to use it.

It could just load an HTML file and convert it to PDF:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.invoice', $data);
return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
```

But I was reluctant to use this package because it seem to rely on `wkhtmltopdf` which seem to not be supported anymore and even the author warns about using it. So I can't take the risk of using it right now (as it's in an organisation)

The other package I found that can support RTL languages is TCPDF, but I could not find a simple way to use it like the barryvdh package.

Is there a way to make TCDPDF read html pages/views instead in a simple way like the above?